# Zoom в msChart. Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, диаграммы

Хочу сделать, что бы при наведении на **ось Х в msChart** и прокруткой колесика, **график** **масштабировался**.
Но! zoom реагирует только когда курсор мыши наведен на подписи оси, а при наведении на пустое место н**ичего не происходит** !

Почему так происходит? и как решить эту проблему?

```
 <chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="mcChart">       
     <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
        <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Name="AxisY"   MouseWheel="LinearAxis_MouseWheel_2"/>                                                   
        <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Name="AxisX"   MouseWheel="LinearAxis_MouseWheel_1"/>
     </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
 </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Answer (score 2):

Небольшой костыль: установите у LinearAxis свойство Background в значение Transparent.
На моей машине работает как магия.

Comment: Этот совет хорош не только для этого отдельного случая. Отсутствие Background'а (вернее, Background = null) в WPF трактуется как прозрачность для событий мыши, поэтому нужен хоть какой-то Background. Transparent -- такой же цвет (#00000000), и концептуально ничем не отличается от, скажем, чёрного.

То есть это скорее всего не костыль, а логичное поведение.

Другое дело, что default-ный фон LinearAxis должен быть более осмысленным.